# Algorithm to move points to get given distance

Tags: algorithm, geometry, distance, points

**I am working on a tool which modifies geometries. One task is to move points that their (Euclidian) distances among each other are bigger than a given distance by considering that the sum of the moved ways is a minimum.** A non-iterative solution which does not measure distances in between is preferred.

I need a algorithm in 3d, but a 1d or 2d explanation as a starting point would be very welcome.

The later coding will be in Python. In case a solution already exists I would use it.

A link to a book or paper related to this problem would be also helpful.

Thanks Hans G

Comment: Could you sketch and describe a small example to illustrate your question?

Comment: So you have a couple of spheres and want to make them non-overlapping. I doubt that there is a closed form solution for that problem. You probably want to solve the an optimization energy that consists of a displacement term (e.g. `Sum_i (xi - si)^2`; `xi` are the positions to be optimized, `si` is the start position of point `i`) and a validity term. The validity term is tricky because it is not smooth. But you could approximate it with a smooth version, e.g. a spline. That term would be `Sum_i Sum j (rho(xi-xj))`. `rho(d)` would give a very large value for `d<radius` and zero for other `d`.

Comment: Hello Nico,thanks for that help. I will try to go that way.

Comment: Here some more Details: The couple of spheres setup is very near to my problem. Actually I have a metal block with certain number of holes that are cylinders and to avoid to high stresses a min distance from hole to hole is needed. The calculation of that distance is time consuming. In addition I have to run another tool after my mod to make sure that the holes end at the b-spline surface of the block. The measurement and the refit need about 2 min. (100 holes). Thus I have to avoid too many iterations of the chain: measurement-->modification->refit.